# How to remove a div that has been created using .append() in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I would like to remove the div created using .append()

Example:
HTML

```
            <input id="type_ingd" type="text">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="add_ingd">
                Add
            </button> 

            <div class="text-left ingd-cont">
                <div class="btn-group incl-ingd">
                    <div type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                        Rooms <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group incl-ingd">
                    <div type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                        Mansions <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

JS

```
            $("#add_ingd").on('click', function(e) {
                var ti = $('#type_ingd').val();
                $( ".ingd-cont" ).append( '<div class="btn-group incl-ingd"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">'+ti+' <i class="fa fa-close"></i></button></div>' );
            });

            $("i.fa-close").on('click', function(e) {
                removeIngd(this);
            });
            function removeIngd(thiscont) {
                $(thiscont).closest('div.incl-ingd').remove();
                var iiv = $(".incl-ingd:visible").length;
                if (iiv == 0){
                    $("#find-recp-btn").attr('style', 'display:none;');
                }
            }
```

First, I try to input a word (ex: kitchen)then click the `Add` button.

Then the word will append inside the `ingd-cont`.

And the problem is when I click the `fa-close` of the word it does not removed..

I'm not sure if this is possible but if it is, please help me out :)

Comment: can't create an event listener on elements that don't exist yet. Research the term *"event delegation"*

Comment: @charlietfl so the append div will never be removed?

Comment: Sure it will if you delegate the event listener as in answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your selector `$("i.fa-close").on('click', function(e) {...});` which does not catch events on elements, which were dynamically added.

The selector can be changed to into this to catch also the dynamically added elements:

```js
$(".ingd-cont").on('click', 'i.fa-close', function(e) {
  removeIngd(this);
});
```

Here is working example. I adjusted your code slightly to make it working properly ;)

```js
$("#add_ingd").on('click', function(e) {
  var ti = $('#type_ingd').val();
  $( ".ingd-cont" ).append( '<div class="btn-group incl-ingd"><div type="button" class="btn btn-default">'+ti+' <i class="fa fa-close">X</i></div></div>' );
});

$(".ingd-cont").on('click', 'i.fa-close', function(e) {
  removeIngd(this);
});
function removeIngd(thiscont) {
  $(thiscont).closest('div.incl-ingd').remove();
  var iiv = $(".incl-ingd:visible").length;
  if (iiv == 0){
    $("#find-recp-btn").attr('style', 'display:none;');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="type_ingd" type="text">
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="add_ingd">
  Add
</button> 

<div class="text-left ingd-cont">
  <div class="btn-group incl-ingd">
    <div type="button" class="btn btn-default">
      Rooms <i class="fa fa-close">X</i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group incl-ingd">
    <div type="button" class="btn btn-default">
      Mansions <i class="fa fa-close">X</i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow it works! Thanks! Now I know that there is this event delegation thing on jquery.